# How can I split a row into multiple rows depending on multiple columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following row (I use the character "|" to separate columns):

```
A, B|1, 2, 3|0, 1, 2
```

and I want to obtain the following rows in a separate sheet:

```
A|1|0
A|1|1
A|1|2
A|2|0
A|2|1
A|2|2
A|3|0
A|3|1
A|3|2
B|1|0
B|1|1
B|1|2
B|2|0
B|2|1
B|2|2
B|3|0
B|3|1
B|3|2
```

I tried the following (`row` is the row I want to split):

```
firstColumn = Replace(row.Cells(1, 1).Value, ", ", ",")
arr1 = Split(firstColumn, ",")

  For Each a1 In arr1

    secondColumn = Replace(row.Cells(1, 2).Value, ", ", ",")
    arr2 = Split(secondColumn, ",")

    For Each a2 In arr2

      thirdColumn= Replace(row.Cells(1, 3).Value, ", ", ",")
      arr3 = Split(thirdColumn, ",")

      For Each a3 In arr3

        DO SOME THINGS HERE

      Next a3
    Next a2
  Next a1
```

This worked. However, now I have to do the same for 15 columns, and I don't feel like doing 15 `For Each`.

Any idea, please?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**
If I have

```
A, B|1, 2, 3|0, 1, 2|"Foo", "Boo"|"Yes", "No"
```

I want:

```
A|1|0|"Foo"|"Yes"
A|1|0|"Foo"|"No"
A|1|0|"Boo"|"Yes"
A|1|0|"Boo"|"No"
A|1|1|"Foo"|"Yes"
A|1|1|"Foo"|"No"
A|1|1|"Boo"|"Yes"
A|1|1|"Boo"|"No"
etc.
```

and I should obtain 2 x 3 x 3 x 2 x 2 = 72 rows. So, all possible combinations.

Comment: How do the other 15 columns look? The same three elements separated by ", "? If yes, how will they be processed? Forget about the code and try presenting a more concludent example. I mean, let the first example like it is, try a second one having 5 columns and show us how the processed result should look. 5 columns with so many rows as possible combination between each element separated by ", "?

Comment: The pattern is the same, no matter the number of columns. Yes, always separated by ",".  I give an example

Comment: So, in the next columns it is not mandatory to be the same number of elements like in columns 2 and 3... OK. I will prepare a piece of code able to deal with 15 such columns, no matter how many elements in each other. I have something in my mind and if you will need to extend it for more columns, I suppose it would be easy to understand its logic.

Comment: 1st column already has different elements. The method I used now with the fors inside the fors takes 2 minutes to create about 1500 rows, which I think is horrible...

Comment: Firstly, the necessary rows for such 15 columns (3 with 2 elements and 12 with 3 elements for each) exceed the Excel available sheet rows (4251528 against  maximum 1048576). Making other four cells with only two elements the range can be processed. I will create such a check point in the code...

Comment: the point is: not all columns will always have the same amount of elements. In one case I can have 7 options in the 3rd column and 6 in the 14th and in a different case I might just have 25 elements in the 2nd column and 2 in the 4th. I am trying to get a general method. Of course if I use all combinations, this breaks! Thank you for your help!

Comment: I almost finished it. It is able to deal with as many elements exists in any column. But, it checks if the maximum necessary rows will be exceeding the Excel sheet possibilities. Working in memory and dropping the processed array at once, I think it should take less then a minute for all accepted range. Theoretically, the code can be adapted to use the next available (columns range) for values exceeding the maximum available. No time now for such a development...

Answer (score 1):

Try the next code, please. It should take less then a minute for all possible range to be processed. I mean, to be inside of 1048576 worksheet maximum number of rows:

```
Sub splitCombineRowCellsInColumns()
Dim i As Long, k As Long, j As Long, l As Long, m As Long, n As Long, o As Long
Dim p As Long, q As Long, r As Long, s As Long, t As Long, u As Long, v As Long, w As Long
Dim NoRows As Long, arrNR As Variant, lastCol As Long, arrFin As Variant, z As Long

lastCol = 15
ReDim arrNR(1 To lastCol, 1 To lastCol): k = 1
For i = 1 To lastCol 'it calculates the necessary number of rows and create arrays for each column
    If NoRows = 0 Then
       NoRows = UBound(Split(cells(1, i).Value, ", ")) + 1
    Else
        NoRows = NoRows * (UBound(Split(cells(1, i).Value, ", ")) + 1)
    End If
    arrNR(k, 1) = UBound(Split(cells(1, i).Value, ", ")) + 1
    arrNR(k, 2) = Split(cells(1, i).Value, ", "): k = k + 1
Next i
If NoRows > 1048576 Then _
        MsgBox "The necessary rows (" & NoRows & _
                ") exceed the maximum available (1048576)": Exit Sub
ReDim arrFin(1 To NoRows, 1 To lastCol) 'Redim the array to keep the processing result
k = 1          'first array element number
For i = 0 To arrNR(1, 1) - 1
    For j = 0 To arrNR(2, 1) - 1
        For l = 0 To arrNR(3, 1) - 1
            For m = 0 To arrNR(4, 1) - 1
                For n = 0 To arrNR(5, 1) - 1
                    For o = 0 To arrNR(6, 1) - 1
                        For p = 0 To arrNR(7, 1) - 1
                            For q = 0 To arrNR(8, 1) - 1
                                For r = 0 To arrNR(9, 1) - 1
                                    For s = 0 To arrNR(10, 1) - 1
                                        For t = 0 To arrNR(11, 1) - 1
                                            For u = 0 To arrNR(12, 1) - 1
                                                For v = 0 To arrNR(13, 1) - 1
                                                    For w = 0 To arrNR(14, 1) - 1
                                                        For z = 0 To arrNR(15, 1) - 1
                                                            arrFin(k, 1) = arrNR(1, 2)(i)
                                                            arrFin(k, 2) = arrNR(2, 2)(j)
                                                            arrFin(k, 3) = arrNR(3, 2)(l)
                                                            arrFin(k, 4) = arrNR(4, 2)(m)
                                                            arrFin(k, 5) = arrNR(5, 2)(n)
                                                            arrFin(k, 6) = arrNR(6, 2)(o)
                                                            arrFin(k, 7) = arrNR(7, 2)(p)
                                                            arrFin(k, 8) = arrNR(8, 2)(q)
                                                            arrFin(k, 9) = arrNR(9, 2)(r)
                                                            arrFin(k, 10) = arrNR(10, 2)(s)
                                                            arrFin(k, 11) = arrNR(11, 2)(t)
                                                            arrFin(k, 12) = arrNR(12, 2)(u)
                                                            arrFin(k, 13) = arrNR(13, 2)(v)
                                                            arrFin(k, 14) = arrNR(14, 2)(w)
                                                            arrFin(k, 15) = arrNR(15, 2)(z)
                                                            k = k + 1
                                                        Next z
                                                    Next w
                                                Next v
                                            Next u
                                        Next t
                                    Next s
                                Next r
                            Next q
                        Next p
                    Next o
                Next n
            Next m
        Next l
    Next j
Next i
'It returns in the same sheet, starting from "Q1", but the processed data are in the array
'and can be dropped very fast (at once) in any other workbook sheet:
 With Range("Q1").Resize(UBound(arrFin, 1), UBound(arrFin, 2))
    .Value = arrFin
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: There are interesting ideas here I'll use, specially to reduce the time needed to compute it. However, my question was about "I don't feel like doing 15 For Each". I wanted to find a way to do this without the 15 fors. Something like "one for for each column + one for to split the elements in the column"...

Comment: @xavier The above algorithm is 100 times more efficient than the one you used. Try it for 15 columns and your computer will crush, if you do not have some NASA technology at home. The above code is completely different against the one you used, in terms of efficiency. On the other hand, I may also want to have more money then Bill Gates. Nobody can stop me, from this point of view... :) I can also imagine a recursive function but IT WILL **NOT** BE MORE EFFICIENT then the above one. It will be only shorter in terms of code lines... And the above code does not use `For Each`...

Comment: yes, as I said, I am using your idea to speed it up, but I'm worried about the day I need to use 17, 24 or 135 columns. Will I have to put 135 ifs nested? That was my original point... Still, thank you very much for the efficiency improvement!

Comment: @xavier It is good to have big targets, but firstly you must count if they can be achieved. It is easy to calculate that using 21 columns with 2 elements for each, it will exceed the available worksheet rows (double then available 2097152/1048576). So, 135 columns for such a processing is something utopic...